# Kotlin compile to java 1.8

Tags: maven, gradle, java-8, kotlin

How to set in gradle and in maven to compile and use jvm with Java 1.8?

gradle

```
compileKotlin.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
compileKotlin.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
```

is this ok?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a `sourceCompatibility` or `targetCompatibility` setting for the Kotlin compiler, you only need the `jvmTarget` option, which you got right. You might want to set it for your tests as well. Overall, this is the config you need:

```
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
```

Alternatively, with different formatting:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Based on the documentation about [using Kotlin with Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#attributes-specific-for-jvm).